# Copying a worksheet messes up Data Validations

Tags: excel, vba

When I am trying to import data from one workbook to another one with the same data needs, the old workbook takes the same references with it. It messes up the data validation in the workbook that I copied to making it = 'OldWorkbookSpecificSheet'!$p$2:$p$3. Is there anything I can do to fix this, or do I just have to created the data validations again every time I want to change something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub CopyWorkbook(WB As String)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim OtherWBVersion As String

    If (OtherWBVersion > "0510") Then
      With ThisWorkbook
         For i = 0 To 19
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "F" & (4 + i * 25) & ":F" & (15 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "G" & (4 + i * 25) & ":S" & (15 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "E" & (18 + i * 25) & ":G" & (24 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "H" & (18 + i * 25) & ":H" & (24 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "J" & (18 + i * 25) & ":K" & (24 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "L" & (18 + i * 25) & ":L" & (24 + i * 25)

           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "N" & (20 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "Q" & (20 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "Q" & (22 + i * 25)
           .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "P" & (22 + i * 25)
            .ImportRange WB, Me.Name, "N" & (22 + i * 25)
         Next i
      End With
     End If
End Sub






    Sub ImportRange(WB As String, WS As String, RngTo As String, Optional   RngFrom As String)
    If RngFrom = "" Then
        RngFrom = RngTo
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range(RngTo).Value = Workbooks(WB).Worksheets(WS).Range(RngFrom).Value
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to copy the sheet? Perhaps a template would serve you better.

Comment: I do use a template to initialize it later on If I would like to fill out the entire sheet with different data, however it takes a very long time to fill in all of the data so that is why I made one for copying, do you think that using the pastespecial xlPasteValues would keep the data validations from travelling between the sheets.

Comment: `xlPasteValues` pastes the values: you'll lose the formulas and the formatting, but yes indeed, you'll lose data validation as well. Copy a sheet copies *everything* on that sheet, including any VBA code-behind.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I fortunately only need the values because I can always reinitialize it with different code without paste values to get them back later on.